# How to make a Portable Server for ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I want my server to be portable so it will be available everywhere when I plug it in to other ubuntu computers.

Like I want to use it at school, I will just have to run a script and the server runs. Or on my friend's computer.

I wonder if this is possible, making servers portable, without re-installing on every other computers. I know that this is possible for windows.

**If you need more information, comment below.**

Portable server, includes, portable " PHP ", "mysql", "phpmyadmin", "apache2". Like the distribution of lampp, but I want that portable.

Is it possible to make lighttpd server portable too?

Comment: Why don't you create a virtual machine? Virtualbox and VMWare player are free on any operating system, you just need to move the VM harddisk image.

Comment: The entire virtual image is not very lightweight compared to a server on my thumbdrive. Furthermore, I was a windows user, I am quite used to the lightweight xampp and portable software. Also, I don't have many files to host.

Answer (score 0):

Sure; you can either specify an amount of extra space on the thumb drive to use as persistent storage when you create a drive using usb-creator normally, or, if you prefer, you can install Ubuntu directly to the thumbdrive as though it were a normal hard drive.  Boot from the thumbdrive, and you're running your "portable server".

Comment: oh, wait, you want the software to run ON other ALREADY BOOTED ubuntu machines?  um, it's *possible*, but it's probably more of a pain than it's worth - you'd need basically to configure each daemon to look for libraries, binaries, spool directories, etc on the thumb drive rather than in the standard location.  You'd also need to be root on any computer you ran this stuff on.  It's *possible*, but I don't think it will be very *practical*.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start off, use Ubuntu's x86(32-bit image), as this will allow you to use both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. Yes, a 32-bit of the server is also available, just take look at the Alternative Downloads page.
Also, I use Lili because its easy and I use Windows for setting up Ubuntu. You can use any other application, although for Method 2, you need an application which allows you to create Persistent Storage.

For method 1, you need another thumb drive(hereon referred to as Thumb drive 2), where you can use a software like LiLi to get that thumb drive bootable to install Linux.(I will also be calling the pendrive which you want to install the portable Ubuntu server version as Thumb Drive 1)

For method 2, you require only one thumb drive(Thumb Drive 1)

Method 1 -

It seems easy(just kidding no not that much).

1. Make thumb drive 2 a bootable Ubuntu installer(eg Using LiLi).(Or, you can even use a CD, and, you need a PC anyways to start off)
2. Install Ubuntu onto Thumb Drive 1, by booting into Thumb Drive 2, so that Thumb drive 1 will now have a fully functional copy of Ubuntu server(You might want to configure it immediately, as the option to install a LAMP server is shown during the installation of Ubuntu Server).
3. Boot into Thumb Drive 1, and configure the server as per your wish.

Method 2 -

1. Using a software that installs a Live Image onto Thumb Drive 1 (I prefer Lili, again), use Persistence to allow for storing of data.
2. Boot into Thumb Drive 1, and configure it.

I personally prefer Method 1, as that way, drivers are installable easily, although rarely, it might not boot properly on certain machines(Not sure about this one, might happen between different chipsets, that is, if you switch between Intel and AMD) .

Various Links -

1. [How to install a LAMP Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)
2. [Download Lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) (Windows)
3. Ubuntu Images - [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)